# Reading huge file and writing in RDBMS

Tags: java, rdbms, distributed-transactions

I have a huge text file which is continuously getting appended from a common place,  which I need to read line by line from my java application and update in a SQL RDBMS such that if java application crashes, it should start from where it left and not from the beginning.

its a plain text file. Each row will contains:
`<Datatimestamp> <service name> <paymentType> <success/failure> <session ID>`

Also the data which is retrieved from database should also be **real time without any performance, availability or availability issues in web application**

Here is my approach:
Deploy application in two systems boxes with each contains heartbeat which pings the other system for service availability.
When you get a success response to heart beat,you also get the time stamp which is last successfully read.
When the next heartbeat response fails, application in another system can take over, based on:
 1. failed response
 2. Last successful time stamp.

Also, since the need for data retrieval is very real time and data is huge, can I crawl the database put that into Solr or Elastic search for faster retrieval, instead of making the database calls ?

There are various ways to do it, what is the best way.

Comment: Are you putting the file contents in a single record in the database, or separate rows in a table? Even without balanced systems, you could just implement a method where on startup, you check if the file is at the same point as the db, and if not, start reading the records (as I presume your application won't be down too long?)

Comment: It would be separate rows in a table.

Comment: the question does not detail the desired "real time" output. is it a report? web application? OLAP? what?

Comment: if you content on using NoSQL database, why go through RDBMS as middle man? you can insert from file directly to the NoSQL database

Comment: what is huge? RDBMS can handle tables with up to 1B rows easily. what is the retrieval requirements? (search criteria) is it only search by fields equal value? is there text search? regular expr? would you need to scan rows and aggregate (sum, avg) all these need to be factor when deciding on DBMS and client application

Comment: search by datatime or field or regex.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a messaging system in between the text file and the DB writing applications. (for example [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)) in this case, the messaging system functions as a queue. one application constantly reads the file and inserts the rows as messages to the broker. on the other side, multiple "DB writing applications" can read from the queue and write to DB.

the advantage of the messaging system is its support for multiple clients reading from the queue. the messaging system takes care of synchronizing between the clients, dealing with errors, dead letters, etc. the clients don't care about what payload was processed by other instances.

regarding maintaining multiple instances of "DB writing applications":  I would go for ready made cluster solutions. perhaps docker cluster managed by kubernates?

another viable alternative is a streaming platform, like [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/).

Comment: how will that take care of data retrieval finally from the database in real time.

Comment: But, make sure to configure Kafka for exactly-one delivery, otherwise you might have your records duplicated in the DB if you have multiple writing apps.

Comment: what are the requirements from the data retrieval? what is the desired output? is it a report? an OLAP? web application?

Comment: web application. End user should be able to select a time stamp.

Comment: so what is the problem to use "regular" web application? RDBMS ensures data consistency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software like FileBeat to read the file and direct the filebeat output to RabbitMQ or Kafka. From there a Java program can subscribe / consume the data and put it into a RDBMS system.